# Secure-Wave and click once applications

Tags: clickonce

I have users who are using "secure-wave" security.  Evidently it is some sort of white-listing application monitor.

With my click-once application, the name of the folders that are used are runtime generated, so the administrators are not able to properly whitelist the application and its files.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way to override the ClickOnce installation location. As you said, it's runtime generated, and resides within the user ClickOnce App Cache within the individual users directory. Have you considered having having the admins whitelisting this specific folder?

I guess the only other way to handle it would be to switch to Windows Installer and implement your update code yourself, which is obviously less than idea. Whitelisting the Click Once cache would be the easiest way, but obviously bare in mind the security considerations of doing this.

Comment: They say they would have to add a rule for each individual user.  I think there has to be a way to use some sort of substitution rule for the user name.

Comment: I would imagine so. Depends on the client machines, but surely on Vista you could have some sort of rule that matched something like C:\Users\*\LocalSettings\etc\etc.

Comment: Securewave doesn't allow the * in the middle.  Only at the end.  I'm trying to get info from the company that currently sells SW, but the version installed at my user's site is older AND no one can find the documentation